# How to cast a type of same class but out of an other package in Java?

Tags: java, casting

There are two classes

`foo.bar.FileUploader` and `barbar.foofoo.FileUploader`

Both are identical and extend `Uploader`

Somewhere in the code the `foo.bar.FileUploader` is used and are given as a parameter to my function as an `Uploader` type.

Now I need to cast it back to `FileUploader` but the `barbar.foofoo.FileUploader`. And this gives an error:

> ERROR - unhandled error
>   `java.lang.ClassCastException`:
>   `foo.bar.FileUploader` cannot be cast
>   to `barbar.foofoo.FileUploader`

And I can't figure out what's going wrong, I suppose it's because the package is different. In that case: Is there a way to still use the class and get the cast done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help people.

I just solved the problem by importing the the barbar.foofoo.FileUploader. Now it runs fine!

Answer (score 7):

Technically they're not the same class.

You're getting a ClassCastException because the JVM doesn't see them as the same type at all. Perhaps you should have both classes implement the same interface and cast to that? Or alternatively, just have one class in the first place and get rid of the cast?

Answer (score 5):

For Java, the classes are not identical. Consider this

```
package zoo;
public interface Animal {}

package zoo.london;
public class Lion implements Animal{}

package zoo.newyork;
public class Lion implements Animal{}
```

Even if the implementation of both `Lion` classes is identical and they both implement a common interface, you can not cast vice versa like

```
zoo.london.Lion lion = (zoo.london.Lion) new zoo.newyork.Lion();  // ClassCastException
```

Comment: Would give ClassCastException in my world

Comment: This will not work, since the classes ARE different (even if they are written the same). It's clear from the error that the problem is not the way he did the cast, since it says he was trying to cast from one to the other. This is only a solution if you don't know how to call the cast since you're using the short class name, and can't tell how to cast to the specific one, and even then it would only work if foo.bar.FileUploader is a child of barbar.foofoo.FileUploader, not a different class, and if you know for sure barbarUploader is an instance of the child class.

Comment: @Kennet, @Andrei - ... I was editing while you commented. Sure, you're right, didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 2):

The two classes foo.bar.FileUploader and barbar.foofoo.FileUploader are NOYT the same as they are defined in different places with different names. Thus java thinks they have no relationship to each other,

If you want then to be identical then you have to make then the same class ie import across the packages. It might be easiest to start refactoring to make one of them extend the other.

Answer (score 2):

Others already said it: The classes are not the same, just because they look like it.
Do the classes implement/extend the same interface/abstract class? cast to the interface or abstract class they are both extended of and use that. What you are trying to do is simply not supported by the JVM. The JVM doesn't care if the classes are identical. If they are really 100 percent identical, it's clearly a messed up design, delete one of the classes.

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html) describes exactly what you are allowed to cast and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of duplicated code. Even if it would work now, because both classes are identical, what would happen if someone edited class A and forgot about class B?

edit: you say they are identical, so I guess they're copies. That would be bad. But since they both extend `Uploader`, you can cast to `Uploader` instead of `FileUploader`.

Comment: You're absolutely right but the class is coming out of a library we made but lost older dependencies needed to work. In further projects we will definitely approach it a different way.