# How do I solve this "cannot be cast to" exception?

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement
    optimise.database.ProdigyDB.doInsertSerial(ProdigyDB.java:139)
    optimise.stock.CurrentRequest.writeRequest(CurrentRequest.java:145)
    optimise.stock.SubmitOrderServlet.processRequest(SubmitOrderServlet.java:51)
    optimise.stock.SubmitOrderServlet.doPost(SubmitOrderServlet.java:188)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    optimise.stock.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:69)
```

The line of code is this:

```
 serial = ((com.informix.jdbc.IfmxStatement) ((org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement) statement).getDelegate()).getSerial();
```

The full function is this:

```
public static int doInsertSerial(String sql) {
    int serial = 0;

    try {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        java.sql.Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);

        serial = ((com.informix.jdbc.IfmxStatement)((org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement) statement).getDelegate()).getSerial();

        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SQL Update Exception\n" + sql, e);                
    }

    return serial;
}
```

This is mysterious because the same code works fine when deployed on a Unix SCO5 server but errors on a Linux Red Hat server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Looking into things a bit deeper, I see that the DelegatingStatement class shows an error:

public class DelegatingStatement extends AbandonedTrace implements Statement {

org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement is not abstract and does not override abstract method isPoolable() in java.sql.Statement

I do not understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement

The package is different for the DelegatingStatement class. `org.apache.commons.dbcp`  & `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp` are two different packages providing two different DelegatingStatement classes. You're getting a ClassCastException because the JVM doesn't see them as the same type at all.

Check the DelegatingStatement class package which is imported. As per the code 
`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp` package should be imported.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367355/java-classcastexception-with-two-identical-classes-in-different-packages-sent-o) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297361/how-to-cast-a-type-of-same-class-but-out-of-an-other-package-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: or if you have more time, you can read [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.id/2012/12/how-to-solve-javalangclasscastexception-java.html#axzz50SF9zzij)